# Validate JSON over XSD schema

Tags: java, xml, json, filter, xsd

I have JSON object which I get from http request body in servlet filter.
I need to validate it over XSD schema. 
Main complexity is that when I convert this JSON object to XML, XMLRootElement is missing and there is no namespace (but in XSD namespace exists ), hence validation is failed.

Also, I cant unmarshall this JSON to POJO, because this web-filter is widespread to a big amount of web-services.

Any ideas?